# Can I use BOOST_TEST_CASE for non-static class member function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I am now using BOOST::UNIT_TEST framework to perform unit test, and it is a great tool to perform unit test. However, I found something inconvenient: when I add functions to test, it seems that the functions must be static or a free function as the following codes illustrate:

```
test_suite* ts = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "unit_test" );

ts->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&static_fun));
```

When it is not a static function, for example,

```
class Abc
{
  public:
    void myfun();

};

Abc obj;
ts->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&(obj.myfun)));
```

then, I will have   `C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments` error. Any idea that I can add the non-static class member function to the test framework? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/manual-nullary-test-case.html)
You can use `boost::bind` for this case.

```
ts->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(boost::bind(&Abc::myfun, obj)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you try to define a test fixture class? The way I use boost test in most cases looks like this:

```
struct MyTestFixture
{
   int test_data;
   void func() 
   {
       // some common test code
   }
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(MyTest, MyTestFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Test1)
{
    test_data = 3;
    func();
    // ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Test2)
{
    // ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```